# Multiple TableView Row Select - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift. I have a `tableView`, and i want the user to select multiple selects. When the user taps on a row i want it to be highlighted and then allow them to select more rows.

My code is as follows:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

        var allCreditCard : AllCreditCard

        allCreditCard = self.creditCard[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = allCreditCard.bankName


//        if(cell.selected){
//            println("cell selected at \(indexPath.row)");
//            let imageName = "tick.png";
//            let image: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName));
//            cell.accessoryView = image;
//        }else{
//            println("cell was NOT selected. Index path----- \(indexPath.row)");
//            let image: UIImageView = UIImageView();
//            cell.accessoryView = image;
//        }


        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

    }
```

How can i solve this. I am not sure how to add the `rowIndex`es and then populate the table with the updated rows. Can someone help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take one array and add all selected `indexPath.row` in it on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` 
and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check for all the objects in that array and set AccessoryType of cell as `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`,

```
if (selectedIndex==indexPath.row) { 
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

} else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

you can do it in swift, logic is the same